# URL Rewrite two different scenarios

Tags: url, url-rewriting

I want to achieve the below:

1. When the URL is https://www.example.com/ it should be redirected to https://www.otherdomain.com/
2. When the URL is https://www.example.com/images/anything, it should stay in the same domain https://www.example.com/images/anything.

How can I do this?

I got the following for 1:

```
<rule name="Rule1">
<match url=".*"/>
<conditions>
<add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="https://www.example.com/"/>
</conditions>
<action type="Rewrite" url="https://www.otherdomain.com/>
</rule>
```

How to create a rule for point 2?